# Why I cannot set text property for a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've decleared a `UILabel` in my view controller

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *statusText;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *statusText;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

Now I want the `UILabel`'s title to change when my button is pressed, but my `statusText` can not set the properly. for example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@button pressed",title];
    statusText.text = @"helloworld";
    NSLog(@"%@",statusText.text);
    [newText release];
 }
```

the log returns

```
   2012-01-25 00:46:27.663 buttonfun[34247:f803] (null)
```

It means that the text property "helloworld" has not been set. Why?

Comment: Is your IBOutlet connected properly in Interface Builder?

Comment: have you synthesize the UILabel?

Answer (score 4):

Try logging this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@",statusText);
```

If it's also null, it means you haven't hooked up your `statusText` IBOutlet to your `UILabel` in Interface Builder (you need to ctrl-drag from your File's Owner to the label and then select `statusText`).